# Website doesn't default to HTTPS

Tags: 301-redirect, https

I'm kinda new to this so bear with me. I just finished setting up SSL on my website. The problem is that if the user types `www.mydomain.com` into their browser, it doesn't connect securely with HTTPS.

However, if I type `https://www.mydomain.com` then it works just fine, and continues to work on subsequent pages, so I know SSL is working.  My question is: how would I set the website so that users connect using SSL by default?

My first thought was to just redirect to the HTTPS version of the page, but that would mean I would have to put a redirect on every page in case the user doesn't come in via the landing page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Apache, you can place the following snippet in the .htaccess file in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Virtual Hosts settings at the httpd.conf level, another option using `mod_alias` would be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost >

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a programming language like PHP (or need another good reason to do so) and including a file at the beginning of every page, you can do a universal redirect easily enough with a few lines of code, such as:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443)
{
    header('Location: https://www.example.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```